# How to find local IP when connected to VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip-address

I have connected an android device to a VPN using the native Android VPN client feature. I need to know the IP the device has been assigned on the VPN subnet, but I can't find it on any Android menu nor with any tool.

Answer (score 1):

Android's VPN uses TUN interface on OSI Layer 3. So you can find what IP is assigned to that interface using Android's built-in command `ip`. From any terminal app or `adb shell`:

```
~$ ip addr | awk '/inet.*tun/ {print $2}'
```